# Google Chrome Web Serial API: How do I address a Modbus device with a hex code?

Tags: javascript, modbus, web-serial-api

It is my intention to address a device with Modbus via the Web Serial API built into Google Chrome. I want to address my device with a HEX code. The following screenshot proves that my device can be successfully addressed with a tool like this.
[image: screenshot]
The interface is thus addressed with the following hex value: 01 03 00 01 00 02 95 CB

My question now is. The [Tutorial](https://web.dev/serial/#write-port) only shows how to address the interface as Uint8Array or Text. How can I address the interface with a HEX code?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Not really understanding your issue; a `Uint8Array` is an array of 8 bit unsigned integers; how you set this (using HEX, Decimal, Octal etc) is not relevant to the end result. For example `Uint8Array([0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x95, 0xCB])`.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array, the `Uint8Array` typed array represents an array of 8-bit unsigned integers.

In JavaScript, `0x` is used to indicate that all subsequent characters should be interpreted as hexadecimal (base 16 number system).

Therefore, all you need would be something like:

```js
const writer = port.writable.getWriter();

const data = new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x95, 0xCB]);
await writer.write(data);
```